# Is this claim true?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Prove or disprove the following claim.
>
> "For all continuous $f : S(0, 1) \to R$, there is a holomorphic $g : B(0, 1) \to C$ which extends to a continu-
> ous $h : B(0, 1) \to C$ such that $\operatorname{Re}(h(z)) = f (z)$ for all $z \in S(0, 1)$?"

$S(0,1)$ is sphere of radius $1$ about the origin, and $B(0,1)$ is open ball of radius $1$ about the origin.

Based on my attempts, this assertion appears to be true, but I am uncertain. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $\displaystyle h(z) = \int_0^{1} \frac{f(e^{2i \pi\theta})}{1 - z  e^{-2 i \pi\theta}}d\theta$

Comment: @user1952009 Thank you. Could you please briefly explain your method?

Comment: fourier series / Z-transform, cauchy integral formula

Comment: @user1952009 Thanks. How can you be certain that a fourier series representation exists? I was of the impression that it only works for periodic functions, yet in this case we don't necessarily have periodicity for any of the functions concerned? Sorry if this seems trivial.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel which is exactly about that